# MAX7219 7-segment via SPI not working

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, led, spi

I am following these instructions to get a simple 7-segment display working:

https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.led_matrix

My problem is that as soon as one of the 3 SPI Pins are connected the digits go off. When running the provided sample script i see no errors, but again, all digits are off.
I already double and triple checked the pin-connections and they are as described in the documentation.
SPI is also enabled. (Checked with `ls -l /dev/spi*` )
As long as just 5V and GND is connected, all digits show '8'.

The display works fine when used with an arduino.

Comment: According to the datasheet for the MAX7219, all the segments should be off if just power is applied.

Comment: Are you driving the display from the 5v on the Pi, can you post a schematic and/or photos? What's the current drawn by your display (better yet do you have a data sheet)? Are you using a level shifter between the Pi and MAX7219?

Comment: @RogerJones the wiring is exactly as in the documentation here https://luma-led-matrix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#gpio-pin-outs no level shifter is used.

Comment: I assume then that you've read the "Notes" section and decided not to use a level shifter to interface the 3.3v Pi to the 5v MAX7219 for some reason? https://luma-led-matrix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes.html

Comment: @RogerJones I did not read the Notes section, as I thought it is only relevant for cascading devices. I assume I need such a 2N7000 Transistor, but what is the "Signal" Pin and what is the normal one?

Comment: The "3.3v" and "5v" pins go the respective supply voltages. The two "signal" pins go to the Pi (3.3v side) and the MAX7219 (5v side). Don't forget to share the ground if you use an external 5v supply.